# Где в exim4 прописать имя отправителя?

Tags: email, exim

Я использую почту для домена и делегировал домен на яндексе. Когда отправляю почту через web интерфейс яндекса, то при получении имя пользователя отображается:

```
от: МоёИмя <мой-имэил>
```

А когда отправляю почту через сайт, то имени отправителя нету:

```
от: <мой-имэил>
```

Сайт отправляет письма через MTA Exim4, настраивал по этой инструкции: https://www.zagirov.name/exim-pdd-yandex-ru/

Как сделать чтоб отображалось имя отправителя?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В теле письма в заголовке `From` вместо `<your@mail.tld>` передавать `"Your Name" <your@mail.tld>`

MTA тут не при чём, эта информация предоставляется отправителем письма.

Answer (score 1):

Если пользователь системный, то можно это указать через `chfn root` поле Full Name для root-а, например.

[Документация](https://www.opennet.ru/base/net/exim_options.txt.html)

от Vasya Pupkin `<admin@server.ru.>`

- Vasya Pupkin - это имя отправителя (опция `-F`)
- admin@server.ru - адрес (опция `-f`)